# new column which the value is coming from the sum of rows (python)

Tags: python, pandas

I need to create a new column which the value is coming from the sum of 3 rows.
My tables looks like this:

```
shoes_type   category     number
sneakers        A           1
sneakers        B           2
sneakers        C           3
heels           A           2
heels           B           1
heels           C           7
```

the new column is expected to be like as follow:

```
shoes_type   category     number     total
sneakers        A           1          NaN
sneakers        B           2          NaN
sneakers        C           3          6
heels           A           2          NaN
heels           B           1          NaN
heels           C           7          10
```

New columns is the sum of every 3 rows of column "number". I want to place the sum of every 3 rows at the last row and let the other rows to be NaN.

How can I make it by using python?

Thankyou :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `transform` with `mask` by `duplicated`

```
df['total'] = df.groupby('shoes_type')['number'].transform('sum').mask(df['shoes_type'].duplicated(keep='last'))
df
Out[52]: 
  shoes_type category  number  total
0   sneakers        A       1    NaN
1   sneakers        B       2    NaN
2   sneakers        C       3    6.0
3      heels        A       2    NaN
4      heels        B       1    NaN
5      heels        C       7   10.0
```

Comment: This is simply brilliant cheers and thanks for sharing :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [`rolling(3)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.rolling.html) if it's always 3 rows:

```
df['total'] = df.groupby('shoes_type', sort=False)['number'].rolling(3).sum().values
```

[out]

```
  shoes_type category  number  total
0   sneakers        A       1    NaN
1   sneakers        B       2    NaN
2   sneakers        C       3    6.0
3      heels        A       2    NaN
4      heels        B       1    NaN
5      heels        C       7   10.0
```